# PHP function() Error , what's the newer Function() of this

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I used that query in PHP but it does not work

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
```

so what should i do ??

Is that is the previous version of PHP so please give me a solution of newer function . Without your answer my project is on pending .

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

First, check your applications server version. It seems like it has been deprecated :

Check it out, you will get the answer :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php